# How can I change what is rendred with a click event in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, and I'm trying to figure out how to adjust what appears in render based on a click event. My component receives two props "front" and "back". I want the component to display `this.props.front` upon rendering and change to `this.props.back` when the div is clicked. I'm having trouble figuring out how to accomplish this in my `handleClick` function.

Any help would be appreciated!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Card extends Component {

handleClick = event => {

}

render() {
return (      
    <div className="Card" onClick={this.handleClick}>
      <h1>{this.props.front}</h1>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: So you want it set to toggle between this.props.front and this.props.back? Or do you want it to just change with no toggle back and forth

Comment: Yes - I'd like to be able to toggle between this.props.front and this.props.back

Comment: Great! I replied in the answers section. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You could add a state to this component which is a boolean that toggles itself

```
class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
    showFront: true
  }
}...
```

And than use your handleClick method to switch the state back and forth

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  this.setState({showFront: !this.state.showFront})
}
```

And in your render function you could put a conditional to show

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="Card" onClick={this.handleClick}>
      {
        this.state.showFront
          ? <h1>{this.props.front}</h1>
          : <h1>{this.props.back}</h1>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

A comment to this answer was made but was deleted - i think it's a subject worth touching.

the comment said you should use the `setState(updater())` and not pass an object.
it's true that when the app becomes more complex, you have several state updates together and data states may not be what you believe they are at that moment, `updater` function is apropriate (setState is async and could batch calls this is why we have the function that flushes all and helps us maintain state integrity comparing old states with new ones.

but for this answer and the complexity of the question an updater isn't necessary and the code should work just fine (and it gets to the point of using state and toggling which is the right way of doing what was asked).

you can use the updater function any time you please - even for the most simplest state change. And like said here, maybe it is best practice to just always use it :)

for more reference
[React.Compoment setState & Updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Thanks - I'd like to keep this as a stateless component if at all possible though.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a great solution. But I think there's a binding problem. showFront is undefined in the handleClick function.

Comment: Sorry fixed it now :) instaed of `!showFront` it should be `!this.state.showFront`

Comment: You're welcome :), please accept as correct answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

In react you trigger render by changing the state of component. If this component needs to recieve props "front" and "back" then parent component should have saved in state if the state is "front" or "back" and pass down to component callback function to handle change. Something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class ParentCard extends Component {
  state = { isFront: true };

  handleClick = event => {
     this.setState({isFront: !this.state.isFront})
  }

 render = () => {

    const { front } = this.state;    


    return (
        <Card front={front} onClick={this.handleClick} />
    );
 };

export default ParentCard;
```

Also you can make `Card` component "pure" just by creating it as function which returns JSX.

```
import React from 'react';


const Card = ( { isFront, onClick } ) => {

     return (

        <div className="Card" onClick={onClick}>

          <h1>{isFront ? `text if is front` : `text if it is not`}</h1>
        </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: On the stateless component example, that's only half the battle as you move the responsibility of the state onto a HoC.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say in that case you want to use `state` rather than `props` here, particularly when the state you want to change is being dictated by the component itself.

```
class Card extends Component {
  state = {
    mode: 'front' // default state to front
  }

  handleClick = () => this.setState({ mode: 'back' })

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Card" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <h1>{this.props.mode}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

If this is really a toggle then of course you can use a Boolean flag instead, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This component itself is currently not set up as a stateless functional component so if thats what you also wanted to achieve. Youll want to make these changes as well as pass props of a boolean in your stateful component.

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {

return (

  <div className="Card" onClick={props.handleClick}>

     {props.showFront 
     ?
     <h1>props.front</h1>
     :
     <h1>props.back</h1>
     }

   </div>

    );
  }

export default Card;
```

you'll want to utilize the previous state to toggle your state because it could cause issues later down the road with batching, so your stateful component should look something like:

```
import React, {Component} from "React";

class StatefulCard extends Component {
  state = {
    showFront: true // default state to front
  }

  handleClick = () => {
   this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
     showFront: !prevState.showFront
    }
  }
}


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card 
         handleClick={this.handleClick}
         showFront={this.state.showFront}
/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```